# Probability of at minimum 1/1000000 of finding a collision

Tags: probability, collision-detection

Let's say I can check for collisions of 100,000 instances of SHA-1(x) in a second. How long would I have to run these computations to have a probability of at least 1/1000000 of finding a collision.

I'm attacking this like a normal probability problem but I think I may be getting 'lost' in the large, and very small numbers.

Essentially what I am looking to calculate is,

```
P(at least one collision) =.000001
```

And we can use the following:

```
P(at least one collision) = 1 - P(no collision)
```

So we need to compute how many instances is necessary for

```
P(no collision) = 0.999999
```

That's where I'm at thus far, and seeking your help!

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on how strong [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is.  Wikipedia says it was originally thought to have strength equal to $2^{80}$ which suggests that it might be equivalent to something like a $160$-bit hash.

For a [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) looking for collisions, the number of values for probability $p$ of a collision is about $\sqrt{2H \log_e \dfrac{1}{1-p}}$, so if $H=2^{160}$ and $p= 10^{-6}$ this would give slightly more than $10^{21}$.

But SHA-1 is not a simple hash function, and indeed Wikipedia describes research that it is not as strong as originally thought.  So in fact this is not the correct order of magnitude.